# When to pass a pointer to a structure as an argument, and when to pass a pointer to a pointer to a structure?

Tags: c, pointers, tree, arguments

My question is in regards to the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int v;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
};

typedef struct node Node;

struct bst
{
    Node * root;
};

typedef struct bst BST;

BST * bst_insert(BST * tree, int newValue);
Node * bst_insert_node(Node * node, int newValue);
void bst_traverseInOrder(BST * tree); 
void bst_traverseInOrderNode(Node * node);

int main(void)
{
    BST * t;

    bst_insert(t, 5);
    bst_insert(t, 8);
    bst_insert(t, 6);
    bst_insert(t, 3);
    bst_insert(t, 12);

    bst_traverseInOrder(t);

    return 0;
}

BST * bst_insert(BST * tree, int newValue)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
    {
        tree = (BST *) malloc(sizeof(BST));
        tree->root = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        tree->root->v = newValue;
        tree->root->left = NULL;
        tree->root->right = NULL;

        return tree;
    }

    tree->root = bst_insert_node(tree->root, newValue);
    return tree;
}

Node * bst_insert_node(Node * node, int newValue)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        Node * new = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        new->v = newValue;
        new->left = NULL;
        new->right = NULL;
        return new;
    }
    else if (newValue < node->v)
        node->left = bst_insert_node(node->left, newValue);
    else
        node->right = bst_insert_node(node->right, newValue);

    return node;
}

void bst_traverseInOrder(BST * tree)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
        return;
    else
    {
        bst_traverseInOrderNode(tree->root);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void bst_traverseInOrderNode(Node * node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    else
    {
        bst_traverseInOrderNode(node->left);
        printf("%d ", node->v);
        bst_traverseInOrderNode(node->right);
    }
}
```

So, the code works perfectly as is. It will insert each value into BST correctly, and the traversal function will traverse the tree inorder correctly. However, when I am initially declaring t to be a BST (e.g. line 27), if I also assign t to be NULL (e.g. BST * t = NULL), then the insertion does not work anymore. But, if I then reassign t for the first insertion (e.g. t = bst_insert(t, 5)), then everything works again. Is there a particular reason for this?

Secondly, how do I know when I need to pass a pointer to a pointer to a structure? If I want to change the value that `int i` points to, then I need to pass `&i` to a function, correct? But if I want to change the values within `struct node n`, then why do I need to pass a `**node` to a function, and not just a `*node`?

Thank you so much for taking a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, *everything* is passed by value, there is no exception to this.

You can *emulate* pass-by-reference by passing the pointer and dereferencing it in the function but this is a poor cousin to real pass-by-reference.

The bottom line is, if you want to change *anything* passed to a function, you have to provide its pointer for dereferencing and, for changing pointers themselves, that means passing the pointer of the pointer. Note that:

```
t = modifyAndReturn (t);
```

is not really the same thing - the function itself does not modify `t`, it simply returns something which the *caller* then assigns to `t`.

So, you've done it the latter way, where you can do something like this:

```
int add42 (int n) { return n + 42; }
:
x = add42 (x);
```

Using the emulated pass-by-reference, that would be (with pointers and dereferencing):

```
void add42 (int *n) { *n += 42; }
:
add42 (&x);
```

For changing pointers, as mentioned earlier, you need to pass the pointer to the pointer. Let's say you want to change a char pointer so that it points to the next character. You would do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pointToNextChar (char **pChPtr) {
    *pChPtr += 1;              // advance the pointer being pointed to.
}

int main (void) {
    char plugh[] = "hello";
    char *xyzzy = plugh;
    pointToNextChar (&xyzzy);
    puts (xyzzy);              // outputs "ello".
}
```

---

C++ actually provides *proper* pass-by-reference with the `&` "modifier" such as:

```
void add42 (int &n) { n += 42; }
```

and you don't have to then worry about derefencing within the function, any changes are immediately echoed back to the original passed parameter. I rather hope that C21 will have this feature, it will save a lot of trouble for people unfamiliar with the pointer gymnastics we have to endure in C :-)

---

By the way, you have a rather serious problem with that code. Within `main`, the line:

```
BST * t;
```

will set `t` to an arbitrary value which is unlikely to be what you want. You *should* set it initially to NULL so that `bst_insert` correctly initialises it.

Comment: Sorry to have so many questions, but one more thing - after I set t to NULL, bst_insert will not modify t (e.g. when I traverseInOrder t, nothing happens). However, if I assign t to the first insert function (e.g. `t = bst_insert(t, 5)`), but don't assign to the rest of the insert functions, even the insert functions that t isn't reassigned to still modify t. Why does this happen?

Comment: @dyxh : traversal requires just the root address initially rest addresses are pointed by right & left. So you **should not** reassign `t` to return value of every insert.

Comment: @dyxh, that's probably best for another question. That way, you'll get more responses. If you ask a question within a comment box as you have, very few people will see it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code is incorrect as it is, because you are not allocating memory for `t` in your main. You will get undefined behavior when you try to access the value pointed in `bst_insert_node`.
The correct way to do it would be to set it to `NULL` and then

```
t = bst_insert(t, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

`BST *t;  // It declares a pointer of type BST`
`BST *t = NULL;  // Declares pointer same way and pointer points to mem location "0"`

Now,

`bst_insert(t, 5);  // Now "tree" pointer inside "bst_insert" definition points to location pointed by "t" i.e. NULL (in 2nd case above)`

`tree = malloc(<some memory>);  // Allocates some memory and stores its base address inside "tree"`

Now see, above statement changes the location pointed by `tree` in `bst_insert()`, but not by `t` in `main()`.

So when you write `t = bst_insert(t, 5)` you return the value pointed by tree explicitly to store in tree, So code works fine.

If you do not use the return value, `t` is still `NULL`.

Either use this way, or you can do like this:

`bst_insert(BST **tree, int new_val);`

And in `main()`

`bst_insert(&t, 5);`

What happens now!!

Now you will use `*tree = malloc(<some mem>);`

So you directly assign base address of memory allocated to: `*tree` which is actually `t` itself. Now you need not return the mem address.

This is same as code below, written inside one function:

```
BST **tree;
BST *t;

tree = &t;
*tree = malloc(<some mem>);  // You are allocating memory and storing address
                             // actually at "t"
```

Hope you understand what I want to explain.